# Sequence Diagram to Communication Diagram

Tags: uml, visio, sequence-diagram, communication-diagram, collaboration-diagram

I have created a Sequence Diagram that I wish to convert to a Communication/Collaboration Diagram. I understand the conversion and the numbering process but I am wondering since my Sequence diagram have loops that are under the alt fragment, how is their numbering going to be in Communication Diagram?

Here a sample of my Sequence Diagram that have one of those loops:
[image]

**Edit:** What I want to know here is that since the loop is an `IF` situation, is it still OK to number those sequences? I don't think it would make logic if user's communication is, `1.0 Enter registered Username and Password`, `2.0 Re-enter registered Username and Password`...2.0 here is the IF loop situation

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Representing loops in a UML communication diagram](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10202095/representing-loops-in-a-uml-communication-diagram)

Comment: @ThomasKilian the other answer is totally not what I am looking for. I have edited my question to be more specific. Thank you anyways for your reply.

Comment: Well, the answer says that you can't do loops in communication diagrams. And that's basically it. You can add comments to show you intention. But then, why not use a SD??

Comment: @ThomasKilian This is actually a part of my project. The requirement needs me to model an SD and CD. I actually saw in other tutorials where the loops are counted as part of the communication. But i felt that it didn't made sense. That's why i wanted to confirm if it is possible. I guess this question have no solid answer then. Maybe then I will specify the IF condition like what you said with adding comments. Thank you very much.

Comment: You "could" number accordingly, but a loop can be performed multiple times (of course). So you would need to use as many numbers as the loop is performed. This will make reading impossible. So simply: in case of loops use a note or better use a SD.

Comment: @ThomasKilian exactly my point with the loop problem. Ok i'll use a note. Thank you.

Comment: I've corrected the title to refer to the communication diagram.  Collaboration diagram is old UML 1.

Answer (score 0):

Communication diagram and sequence diagram represent the same interactions from a different angle. But the simplified graphical representation of the messages implies restrictions in the communication diagram when it comes to combined fragments.

In the communication diagram you can represent:

- simple sequence of messages and nested messages, via the chronological numbering, e.g.: `1`,`2`,`3` and decimal numbering, e.g. `2.1`, `2.2`, `2.2.1`
- loops (`loop` operator in sequence diagram), using a `*` following the number.  More specific looping specifications could follow the start between brackets e.g. `*[1..n]` or `*[element in collection]`.  Your loop conditions are unspecified in the sequence diagram, so a `*` would do.
- simple conditions (`opt` operator in sequence diagram), using a condition between brackets after the number e.g.`[t>10]`

In your example, we could therefore imagine:  `

```
1: Enters username and passord
2: Check validity
2.1*: Mismatch of name or password    // return message, not usual     
2.2:  Prompt user to re-enter credentials
2.3:  Re-enter username and password
2.4:  Re-check validity               // missing in the SD in the loop
3: Verify user
4: USer verified
5: Display profile
```

Now there are two issues here:  first, in your sequence diagram,  there is a missing `check validity` in the loop. Second, I showed for simplicity all the messages, but in a communication diagram you would usually not sho return messages, to keep things simpler.  So we'd have a slightly simpler model:

```
1: Enters username and passord
2: Check validity   //message, return is implicit
3.1*[credentials invalid]: Prompt user to re-enter credentials      
3.2: Re-enter username and password
3.3: Check validity 
4: Read user
5: Display profile
```

Advice for the choice between SD and CD:

- if you have many involved lifelines, either make several smaller SDs or opt for the CD.
- if you have many message exchanges, especially between the same lifelines, prefer SD, because following the numbers on a CD is exponentially unintuitive with the increase of messages, and long lists of messages above the arrows look ugly.
- if you have many combined fragments, or if you have more than loops and optionals, stay with SD.